# Upgrading to Vaadin 23.2.1 - java.net.MalformedURLException: Error at index 5

Tags: vaadin

After upgrading my Vaadin application from 23.1.x to 23.2.1 I encountered the following exception when I attempt to open the landing page:

```
    java.net.MalformedURLException: Error at index 5 in: "38593VAADIN"
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:679)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:541)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:488)
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.prepareConnection(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:609)
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.ViteHandler.prepareConnection(ViteHandler.java:153)
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner.serveDevModeRequest(AbstractDevServerRunner.java:707)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.StaticFileServer.serveStaticResource(StaticFileServer.java:243)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.serveStaticOrWebJarRequest(VaadinServlet.java:396)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:351)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
```

One contributing factor to this, I believe, is that I have configured my Vaadin application to be co-hosted with other services. I.e. only serve specific URL patterns. Hence I have configured the Vaadin servlet like:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/ui/*","/VAADIN/*"}, name = "configurationServlet", asyncSupported = true)
public class WebAppConfigurationServlet extends VaadinServlet
{
}
```

If I change the servlet mapping to :

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/*"}, name = "configurationServlet", asyncSupported = true)
```

It does work. However, it then breaks the rest of my application.

Does anyone perhaps have advice as to how to proceed? This certainly looks like a regression of sorts. But is there perhaps a better, more compatible, way for me to achieve this aim?

Comment: Small update on this item - as per recommendation from the Vaadin team, I added in the following flag:

`com.vaadin.experimental.webpackForFrontendBuild=true`

As per https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/configuration/live-reload#webpack-feature-flag . And that seemed to resolve the issue.

Hence it would indicate a regression in the Vite handler. Awaiting further instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed related to your additional `/VAADIN/*` mapping and you can remove that. Then it will magically work. Vaadin looks at the available servlet mappings and picks one to use to serve frontend files. In this case it happens to pick `/VAADIN` as the prefix to use and then something goes wrong after that when it also uses `/VAADIN` inside the servlet path to refer to static resources.

I also made a fix for this in https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/14677 so that it will work in the future even with a extra `/VAADIN/*` mapping